# ViewCell Buttons to Update ViewModel Property

Tags: xamarin, button, binding, viewmodel

I have a custom `ViewCell` class. I want to add increment/decrement buttons to this class which adjust an integer property of the bound viewmodel.

I'm new to Xamarin and am struggling to determine how to implement this and how data-binding works in general in Xamarin.

(I'm doing this because the Stepper control is too tiny to actual be usuable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create a custom ViewCell**

> MyViewCell.xaml

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="xxx.MyViewCell">
 <ViewCell.View>       
        <StackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    >
            <Button
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30"
                    Clicked="BtnMinus_Clicked"
                    Text="-"
                    x:Name="btnMinus"
                    FontSize="10"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    TextColor="Green"
                    BorderColor="Green"/>
            <Entry

                        x:Name="myEntry"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{Binding value}"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        FontSize="10"
                        Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Button
                        x:Name="btnAdd"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="30"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked"
                    Text="+"
                    FontSize="10"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    TextColor="Green"
                    BorderColor="Green"
                    />
        </StackLayout>     
 </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

> MyViewCell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyViewCell: MyViewCell
{
    public ViewCell1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }


    private void BtnMinus_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = int.Parse(myEntry.Text) - 1;
        myEntry.Text = num.ToString();
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = int.Parse(myEntry.Text) + 1;
        myEntry.Text = num.ToString();
    }
}
```

**2. create a ViewModel**

```
public class Data
{
    public string value { get; set; }      
}
```

**Text="{Binding value}"** in your Custom ViewCell will binding with the property of value of **Data**.

Data binding is the "glue" that binds the properties of a user interface object to the properties of some CLR object, such as a class in your ViewModel. Data binding is useful because it simplifies the development of user interfaces by replacing a lot of boring boilerplate code.

Data binding works by keeping objects in sync as their bound values change. Instead of having to write event handlers for every time a control's value changes, you establish the binding and enable binding in your ViewModel.

**3. Binding Cells **

in your content page.

> xxxpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx"
         x:Class="xxx.xxxPage">

 <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyViewCell Height="150" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

> xxxPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class xxxPage : ContentPage
 {
    public ObservableCollection<Data> mySource { get; set; }

    public xxxPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        mySource = new ObservableCollection<Data>();


        mySource.Add(new Data { value = "0" });
        mySource.Add(new Data { value = "1" });
        mySource.Add(new Data { value = "2" });
        mySource.Add(new Data { value = "3" });
        mySource.Add(new Data { value = "4" });
        mySource.Add(new Data { value = "5" });

        MyListView.ItemsSource = mySource;
    }
 }
```

Note that the binding was setup in code for simplicity(**BindingContext = this**;
), although it could have been bound in XAML.

The previous bit of XAML defines a ContentPage that contains a ListView. The data source of the ListView is set via the ItemsSource attribute. The layout of each row in the ItemsSourceis defined within the ListView.ItemTemplate element.

This is the result:

[image]

For more detail about ListView and datebinding you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding).

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer.